# Why won't my hangman program work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to make a hangman program, and I need to give the variable newWord the same length as the original word but only filled with underscores. This is my code:

```
word = [r.choice(WORDS).lower()]
origWord = word
for item in origWord:
    newWord += "_"
```

However, whenever I run it, it returns:

```
-----------
|         |
|
|
|
| 
|
|
------------


_

Take a guess:
```

with the single underscore as the "newWord". Any tips?

Comment: What is the value of `word` in your example?

Comment: Your `word` is a *list* with one element, despite what the name seems to indicate.  When you make a string with one underscore per element, you're obviously going to get only one underscore.  You probably don't want those square brackets in the first line you posted.

Comment: If you have a list with one element, doesn't each letter in the word become an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without a complete example, but the first line

```
word = [r.choice(WORDS).lower()]
```

this is a list with one element in it. Thus your code below is adding one underscore for each element in this list. I expect that removing the `[]` is enough to make this work

```
word = r.choice(WORDS).lower()
```

However you don't need the for loop to get the number of underscores, you can just do

```
newWord = '_' * len(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for the newWord tip, but I need the word to be a list so that I can manipulate it later. Would it be fine as is (with newWord = '_' * len(word))?

Comment: @I.Green if I understand you correctly you want to go from something like `"hey"` to `['_', '_', '_']`. Keep the assignment to `word` the same as I've shown and do `['_'] * len(word)`

Answer (score 0):

I would try making an empty array and then use a for loop to insert underscores to the list. Once this is done, combine the underscores by using the `'_'.join()` command. For example:

```
a = []
b = int(input('How many characters is your word? '))
for i in range(0,b):
    a.append('_')
c = ' '.join(a)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
How many characters is your word? 7
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
>>>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You've got 13 underscores there. I think you're looking for `' '.join(a)` or `''.join(a)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try somethink like:

```
newWord = ''.join(['_'*len(word)])
```

Comment: This is insanely overcomplicated.  Even if producing the string of underscores was the actual problem, `'_'*len(word)` alone would do the job.